# Using a generic RootObject to handle JSON with different property names at the root

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Json.Net and I am looking for thoughts on how to change a JsonProperty name during deserialization at run time.  Why you might ask, mainly because I do not like have a large number of "RootObject" classes floating around that have the exact same structure.

Consider the following "root objects".

```
 public class Rootobject1
 {
     [JsonProperty("tasks")]
     public List<Task> Data { get; set; }
 }

 public class Rootobject2
 {
     [JsonProperty("projects")]
     public List<Project> Data { get; set; }
 }

 public class Rootobject3
 {
     [JsonProperty("countries")]
     public List<Country> Data { get; set; }
 }
```

Seems like an awful lot of redundant code.  So I am looking for options.  Some that come to mind are:

Something that uses an attribute parameter for some simple conditional logic:

```
 public class Rootobject<T>
 {
     [JsonProperty("projects", whenType=typeof(Project))]
     [JsonProperty("tasks", whenType=typeof(Task))]
     [JsonProperty("countries", whenType=typeof(Country))]
     public List<T> Data { get; set; }
 }
```

or maybe something along the lines of a runtime configuration?

```
 var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject<Project>>(json, RootName="projects")

 var tasks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject<Tasks>>(json, RootName="tasks")
```

So I am curious, has anyone come up with a creative and elegant way of handing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a custom contract resolver.  The resolver can effectively change the JSON property name the serializer looks for at run time.  Here is the code you would need:

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    string rootName;

    public CustomResolver(string rootName)
    {
        this.rootName = rootName;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(RootObject<>))
        {
            JsonProperty prop = props.First(p => p.UnderlyingName == "Data");
            prop.PropertyName = this.rootName;
        }

        return props;
    }
}
```

The next piece is to create a helper method to apply the resolver when you deserialize:

```
public static RootObject<T> Deserialize<T>(string json, string rootName)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(rootName);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject<T>>(json, settings);
}
```

You can then call the helper as you wanted in your question:

```
RootObject<Project> projects = Deserialize<Project>(projectJson, "projects");
```

Full demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yEBLkx

Comment: Good point, only issue is that gets in the way of using the Contract Resolver for various IoC containers (which I am currently leveraging and is unfortunately a sealed class).

Nice thought though.